# Adding data using javascript to form

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am a little confused as to why I am getting no results for this...

```
<?php
                $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database');
                $query = "SELECT id, size, color, quantity FROM `".$searchitem."`";
                $res2 = $link->query ( $query ) or die(mysqli_error($link));
                if ($res2->num_rows > 0) {
                    while ( $row2 = $res2->fetch_assoc () ) {
                        ?>
                        <script>
                            addData(<?php echo $row2["size"]?>, <?php echo $row2["color"]?>, <?php echo $row2["quantity"]?>);
                        </script>
                        <?php
                    }
                }
                ?>
```

Nothing appears to be working in the script...

```
function addData(size, color, quantity){
var i=1;
i++;
$('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="text" name="size[]" placeholder="Size.." value="'+size+'" class="form-control name_list" /><td><input type="text" name="colors[]" placeholder="Colors.." value="'+color+'" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td style="width: 20px;"><input type="number" name="quantity[]" placeholder="Quantity.." value="'+quantity+'" /></td></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');
```

}

Comment: quotes around the params your passing in. check console for errors.. also var i will be reset each time so it will always be 2

Comment: Take a look (and post) at the generated JavaScript, also check your debug console for JS errors. Chances are you're missing quotes in your addData call.

Comment: There are no errors that I'm getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, mixing PHP and Javascript is not ideal. There are two solutions. First:

```
<div id="dynamic_field">
 <?php
     $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database');
     $query = "SELECT id, size, color, quantity FROM '$searchitem'";
     $res2 = $link->query ( $query ) or die(mysqli_error($link));
            if ($res2->num_rows > 0) {
                while ( $row2 = $res2->fetch_assoc () ) {
                   echo $row2["size"]?>, <?php echo $row2["color"]?>, <?php echo $row2["quantity"]?>);
                }
            }
 ?>
</div>
```

Second, wrap your function with the following snippet and put the whole php snippet at the bottom of the page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 // put your function here
});
```

However, echoing a JS function with PHP is not ideal because the JS file might have been downloaded when the DOM is renderd by PHP. This means that `addData()` may be undefined.

I also highly suggest that you create a class in dbConfig for mysqli_connect and make it a private function.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that php snippet is positioned preferably at the end of the body, or after the #dynamic_field element, as you might be executing javascript on a element which has yet to load.